# how to really solve the DLL load failed and _pywrap_tensorflow_internal issues

Tags: tensorflow

Following is my log, I can use the very old version of '0.12.0-rc0', but for tensorflow 1.3 it fails.

I have to use at least tensorflow 1.0, so that I can follow my teacher.

I have been searching this issue for days and the answers cannot really help.

Can anyonw help ?

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模块。

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: even I got stuck in the same place

Comment: any solutions for this issue?